# How to show Realm Data base results to an edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, realm

so I'm new to realm data base and I'm trying to show the data that the user wrote throw an Edit text and show it in a Textview..

**My realm class**

```
     import io.realm.RealmObject
    import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey
    import io.realm.annotations.RealmClass

@RealmClass

open class GoodStudents : RealmObject(){
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long = 0
    var name : String? = null
    var grade : Int? = null


}
```

**Main activity code**

```
Realm.init(this)
    val convig = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name("GoodStudents").build()
    val realm = Realm.getInstance(convig)
    realm.beginTransaction()

    count = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll().size

    val goodStudents = realm.createObject(GoodStudents::class.java, count+1)
    goodStudents.name = name.text.toString()
    goodStudents.grade
    realm.commitTransaction()


        val readData = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll()

    saveButton.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        var text = text.text
        readData.forEach { save ->
           save.name = text as String?


        }

    }
```

P.C. Java code is acceptable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found out that writing this code will work 
    saveButton.setOnClickListener {

```
        val convig = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("GoodStudents").build()
        val realm = Realm.getInstance(convig)
        realm.beginTransaction()

        count = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll().size
        val goodStudents = realm.createObject(GoodStudents::class.java, count+1)
        goodStudents.name = name.text.toString()
        goodStudents.grade = grade.text.toString().toInt()

        val readData = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll()

        readData.forEach { save ->

            text.text = ""  + save.name + ": " + goodStudents.grade

        }

        realm.commitTransaction()

    }
```